# how to send an object that contains an image to server via json

Tags: java, android, json, service, bitmap

I have an Object Student that contains :

```
int studentId;
String name;
byte[] picture;
```

I want to send it to server.
  I tried to send it via json, but the object can't be converted to json because the `byte[] picture;` too large.

Is it possible at all to send the image in an object or it has to be sent separately?

thank's :)

Comment: you want to store in database?

Comment: Do you have other options than json?

Comment: You want to send it to the server? From where? Are you uploading the image from somewhere? Can you give us more details?

Comment: I think you should create a seperate thread for uploading the images. Send the image's id in your json and then upload the image bytes with a asynctask and include the id you passed in the json. This way you can determine what the image should be linked to.

Comment: I cupture image and i save it in byte [] and when i try convert to json it's stuck

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Base64 image splitting it into smaller sub-strings. and then you can convert to json.